# How do I vertical align a footer inside a card with equal height but flexible body part with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, sticky-footer

I have made this minimum case scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/frp61gh7/

the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>card</h2>
    <p>
    some body text. Doesn't really matter. However dit part can have various length. For instance and large image or more text then usual. In that case all other cards should be equally high of that row..
    </p>
    <div class="footer">
    <p>
    this is some kind of footer that should always stick to the bottom
</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">x5...etc</div>
</div>
```

the CSS:

```
.row{
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card{
  width: 31%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0.5%;
}
.footer{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
p{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

where I have 6 cards that flow in a flexbox container just as I want. (blue border) The cards are equal in height and flow the way I want. The height of the cards per row may vary to the up-most highest card of that row. In the real-live scenario this works.

However, the body of each card can be high or low depending on it's content (for instance in the real-life scenario the width of the productimage is fixed but the height is variable).
Now the question/problem: because the body is flexible in height I can't seem to get the footer-div (red border) to the bottom innerpart of the card. position: absolute is no option because I tried this and this get messy with the flexible body.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Make the cards flex-containers and set the direction to column and then give the footer `margin-top:auto`.

This pushes the footer the bottom of each column.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 31%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0.5%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: auto;
}

p {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="card">
    <h2>card</h2>
    <p>
      some body text. Doesn't really matter. However dit part can have various length. For instance and large image or more text then usual. In that case all other cards should be equally high of that row..
    </p>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        this is some kind of footer that should always stick to the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>card</h2>
    <p>
      smaller piece of body..
    </p>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        this is some kind of footer that should always stick to the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>card</h2>
    <p>
      And this piece of body will be of medium size. I just have to see how I can fill this with nonsense text. I'm drinking a cup of coffee and working at home because of Corona.
    </p>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        this is some kind of footer that should always stick to the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>card</h2>
    <p>
      some body text. Doesn't really matter. However dit part can have various length. For instance and large image or more text then usual. In that case all other cards should be equally high of that row..
    </p>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        this is some kind of footer that should always stick to the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>card</h2>
    <p>
      smaller piece of body..
    </p>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        this is some kind of footer that should always stick to the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>card</h2>
    <p>
      And this piece of body will be of medium size. I just have to see how I can fill this with nonsense text. I'm drinking a cup of coffee and working at home because of Corona.
    </p>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>
        this is some kind of footer that should always stick to the bottom</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition

I have found a hackish way of solving things for now for as long as there is no better answer. Might help others and/or it might give a sense of what I want the endresult to look like:

In my own sollution I added a placeholder (yes, going back to relic techniques) with the same height as the footer..

fiddle of the riddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfo42nh8/

CSS:

```
.row{
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.placeholder{
  height: 100px;
}
.card{
  width: 31%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0.5%;
  position: relative;
}
.footer{
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="card">
    <h2>card</h2>
    <p>
    piece of body that needs flexible height..
    </p>
    <div class="placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    <p>
    footer content
</p>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- x 5 extra..you get the idea -->
</div>
```